# Different flowers have same colour

Tags: biochemistry, botany, perception, flowers

I notice that certain (wild) flowers have the same colour, although they are not closely related. For example, the yellows of the dandelion (Taraxacum) and the buttercup (Ranunculus) are, at least to my eyes, identical (my observations are in the Netherlands).

[image: Buttercup and Dandelion]

I know that the colour is intended to attract insects; is this parallel evolution or are there certain biochemicals which provide colour and are easy for the plant to synthesize? Or something else?

**Edit**: I used the buttercup and dandelion because that was the first pair I found physically close enough for a photo; the cowslip, celandine and charlock mustard are all (to my eyes) the same yellow. I have also seen similar blues, reds and violets, and shall try to collect examples next time I go cycling on the dyke.

When I look at colour tables like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Extended_colors I see numerous colours which I do not recall ever seeing in wild flowers.

**Edit2:** I retract my remarks about blues, reds and violets; it's hard to judge colours when cycling past and when I pluck the flowers and compare directly there's a definite difference, for example:
[image: four pink flowers]

However I still find the yellows very similar; here the charlock (left) is lighter but the buttercup, celandine and dandelion look identical *to my eyes*.
[image: four yellow flowers]

Comments seem to suggest a biochemical cause; can anyone confirm (or disprove) it?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but note that many insects see a different spectrum that we do — for example bees can see into the ultraviolet, but IIRC don't see reds. Consequently, what we see isn't necessarily a good representation of what an insect pollinator sees — in fact the UV pattern on a dandelion may be very different from that on a buttercup. Search for [`"UV" images of buttercups and dandelions`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22UV%22+images+of+buttercups+and+dandelions) to see example images.

Comment: Antheraxanthin, is the pigment that is causing the yellow colour in dandelions. It is built from a basic carotene molecule. Carotene is a another basic pigment that is found in many plants specifically to produce colour. Antheraxanthin in dandelions, is associated with photoprotection from the sun. Possible topics you should explore to understand your questions are: carotenoids, flavonoids, and anthocyanins, all of these molecules groups are associated with flower pigmentations.

Comment: [link](https://phys.org/news/2011-12-scientists-buttercups-yellow-chins.html) Here is a article about buttercups, apparently the the pigment molecule in buttercup is also a derivative of  carotenoids, just like dandelions. Though the purpose for the presence of the pigment is totally different. As mentioned by @tyersome, the pigment in buttercup produces different UV colour, which some animals see and this feature brings about different physical properties such as reflectivity that is seen in buttercups and not dandelions.

Comment: Wow! You guys are fast! tyersome's link seems to exclude parallel evolution, and Sentma's data suggests a biochemical explanation. Is anyone confident enough to make an answer?

Comment: @NL_Derek, could you make your question a bit more clear, at its current state it is a bit vague.

Comment: You might consider that there are many fewer colors (at least to human perception) than there are species of plants with showy flowers.

Comment: @Sentma is this an improvement?

Comment: WRT those color tables, note that there are many more colors there than can be distinguished by the average human.  Honestly,  can you tell the difference between LawnGreen, Chartreuse, and GreenYellow,  or between Firebrick and IndianRed?

Comment: @jamesqf valid observation, but my point is that I don't recall ever seeing a flower with, for example, LightSlateGray or RosyBrown.

Comment: @NL_Derek: Perhaps you haven't looked hard enough?  Here's a local wildflower that approaches RosyBrown: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paeonia_brownii  You could probably find grays in for instance Aril & Arilbred irises.  Like this one: https://garden.org/plants/view/527214/Arilbred-Iris-Iris-Eyes-on-You/  (I really can only approximate the particular shades myself.)

Comment: @jamesqf your remarks led me to check further and I have now restricted the question to yellow. Also I suspect Dutch dykeside wild flowers are less varied than in your locality, alongside yellow and white I see mostly shades of blue, pink and purple/violet.

Comment: @NL_Derek: Perhaps - I've never been to the Netherlands.  (And the Aril Irises are definitely not wildflowers hereabouts, being native to the Middle East.)  But even within some species, there are considerable color variations.  For instance, the common wild California poppy (Eschscholzia californica) is usually a bright orange, but it's not that uncommon to see plants with bright yellow flowers, or intermediate shades: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschscholzia_californica

Answer (score 1):

I think parallel evolution is likely due to the cost to produce the pigments in plants.

Xanthophylls and carotenes are made from only carbon, oxygen and hydrogen. This provides most of the yellow colours without using up nutrients.

Anthocyanins and betalains also need nitrogen, which can be a limiting nutrient for plants.

Wikipedia has a section on plant pigments at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_pigment

Comment: +1 for the Wikipedia link